# Observable only works when subscribed to twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

```
this.companyData$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.visibleStatusTypes$,
    this.queryParamsStream$
  ).map(...)
```

Only fires if I do:

```
this.companyData$.subscribe(() => console...)
this.companyData$.subscribe(() => console...)
```

Subscribing once doesn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: Use forkJoin instead. combineLatest does not emit the initial value

Comment: It depends on what `this.visibleStatusTypes$` and `this.queryParamsStream$` are. I guess at least one of them is Subject.

Comment: @martin there is a subject higher up the stream, it combines to make `this.visibleStatusTypes$`

Comment: `combineLatest` emits only when all source Observable emit at least one item so when you have Subjects they probably emit after you subscribe to the Observable you created with `combineLatest` but it's hard to tell what exactly is your use-case. Make a demo on eg. stackblitz if you can reproduce the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was because `this.visibleStatusTypes$` was a `Subject`, changing this to a an `BehaviorSubject` fixed everything.